# Swift Class is not constructible

Tags: constructor, swift

I'm following along with the iBook for swift programming, but I am getting an error when I try to contruct a class with var.  Here is a stuct and a class:

```
struct Resolution {
    var width = 0
    var height = 0
}

class VideoMode {
    var resolution = Resolution()
    var interlaced = false
    var frameRate = 0.0
    var name: String?
}
```

I can create an instance of the Resolution struct just fine, but I can't seem to make one for VideoMode Class.

```
    var r = Resolution()
    println("Width:\(r.width) Height:\(r.height)")
    r.height = 1234
    r.width = 9877
    println("Width:\(r.width) Height:\(r.height)")
    var vm = VideoMode() //Says that 'VideoMode' is not constructible with ()
    let vm = VideoMode() //Apparently this works though.... why?
    vm.resolution.width = 22222
    vm.resolution.height = 1234
    vm.name = "Calimari"
    print(vm)
```

I find this strange can anyone explain?

Update:
Apparently it works ok in playground.  I am not running this in playground.  I am running it using the master detail template using swift code.  I added the "var vm = VideoMode()" in the viewDidLoad method and I get an error.  But it seems to be ok if I change it to "let".  No clue why that makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: is that the exact code you have? It's working fine for me

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a playground and it works fine for me, too.

Comment: show the error message

Comment: I'm running it in the MasterView Detail template.  Inside the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I believe you forgot the question mark after name: String. This would make name not an optional and you would need to set a default value for that.. that is the only explanation I find for the error. It works fine for me.

Comment: @ViniciusMiana you mean when I set the values? It doesn't seem to make a difference. e.g. vm.name? = "Calimari"

Comment: No, I mean when you declared the class. Your code in the post is perfect, but you missed the question mark in the VideoMode declaration, you would get that error.

Comment: I did not miss the question mark.  However, when I removed the question mark it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't define **default values** for all stored properties then you **must** define `init()`.

```
var name: String?    // There's no default value here.     Either set name to `nil` or define init()
```

Exerpt from the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html):

> Classes and structures *must* set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the property’s definition. These actions are described in the following sections.

---

### Addendum:

As stressed by user @valfer, I've [found the following](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_315):

> #### Optional Property Types
>
> [...] Properties of optional type are automatically initialized with a value of nil, indicating that the property is deliberately intended to have “no value yet” during initialization.

I ignore if the above was present from the get-go or if it was added after the fact as the language is in beta at the time of this writing and is still in flux.

Comment: It is an optional, so it has a default value

Comment: @valfer  Actually, no, it doesn't.  Much like an `enum`, an Optional does not have an implicit default value.

Comment: mmh... If you put the two classes in the same source file, it compiles right! See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807074/swift-optional-property-error and github project: https://github.com/valfer/OptionalBug

Comment: @valfer, Then I would file that under buggy behaviour. There is nothing in the language specification (to date) that indicates -- implicitly or explicitly -- that enumerations nor optionals have default values. *I mention both here because I believe optionals are expressed as enums under the hood.*

Comment: I agree it must be a bug with beta.
Also from Swift Documentation: 
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the Question mark at the end of the "name" variable declaration was preventing this from constructing.

```
//Implementation file of VideoMode
class VideoMode {
    var resolution = Resolution()
    var interlaced = false
    var frameRate = 0.0
    var name: String = "" //removed the question mark 
}

//.....in another class
var vm = VideoMode(); //seems to work after making the above changes to the class declaration
```

Comment: You can keep the question mark, just need to define a default value. `var name: String? = nil` would do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you forget to put `: NSObject`

like this:

```
class VideoMode: NSObject {
    var resolution = Resolution()
    var interlaced = false
    var frameRate = 0.0
    var name: String?
}
```

Comment: i think that there is no need to inherit from NSObject

Comment: You are right if you put the `VideoMode` declaration and the `var vm = VideoMode()` thing in the same file. However when I put the `VideoMode` declarion in another file such as `VideoMode.swift` and  try to instantiate it from `Player.swift` then I must inherit it from NSObject or else the not constructible error will show up.