# Swift optional property error

Tags: swift, ios8

I have a class so defined:

```
class User {

    var name : String?
}
```

I use it in my ViewController using the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let user : User = User()
}
```

I have the compilation error

> User is not constructible with ()

I know that the properties in Swift must have a default, but the optional has one (nil). The error disappear if I initialize the property "name" to nil or add an init() initializer. But I don't understand why my optional has not nil by default.

By the way, the following code in playground compiles perfectly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let user : User = User()
}

class User {

    var name : String?
}
let vc = ViewController()
```

And it is strange.

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028786/swift-class-is-not-constructible) but I don't understand the answer there (why the optional has default in the playground but not in the app?).

**EDIT**: The error happens only if the User class is defined in a separated file. XCode is Beta 3 (see images)

[image: XCode Versione]

[image: User class file]

[image: view controller file]

Comment: that error does not appear on my side. I've compiled the project with no further issues.

Comment: Have you tried the project as the screenshots in my edit?

Comment: Bug is also in current XCode 6.0 GM (6A313), Swift version 1.0 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should file a bug report -- this is definitely incorrect behavior by the compiler. When you try to initialize that way you're using the *default initializer* -- [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) states:

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or base class
>   that provides default values for all of its properties and does not
>   provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer
>   simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their
>   default values.

Then shows this example:

```
class ShoppingListItem {
    var name: String?
    var quantity = 1
    var purchased = false
}
var item = ShoppingListItem()
```

Then says in the following paragraph:

> ... (The `name` property is an optional `String` property, and so it
>   automatically receives a default value of `nil`, even though this
>   value is not written in the code.) ...

Comment: Thank you, my opinion also is that it is a bug of the current beta

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in an iOS app using Xcode 6 beta 3 and it just compiles and runs fine.

The code is **the same**:

```
class User {
    var name : String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let user : User = User()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

and if I set a breakpoint on this line:

```
let user : User = User()
```

it stops as expected.

Are you using beta 3? Have you double checked your code to be sure that it's actually what you've posted here?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Beta 3. I think your code works as expected because the two classes are in the same source file. See my Edit.

Comment: I tried the code from github, and indeed it doesn't compile The only way is to explicitly add an empty initializer *or* initializing the variable to `nil`. Definitely a bug in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to compile you write your user class like this, might not be ideal, but seems to work in [github.com/valfer/OptionalBug](http://github.com/valfer/OptionalBug)

```
class User {

    var name : String?

    init() {

    }
}
```

Comment: or: class User {
    var name : String? = nil
}